Zoom level plugin : better UI? Alternate solutions?
Zoom level plugin is very useful when designing maps.
I don't know why QGIS does not integrate it. (Or I missed something)
I notice that the zoom level displayed is systematicaly overwritten by the QGIS command status messages. Is it be possible to move the display near the "coordinate" box? Or at another place?
I have the feeling also that the zoom level information is given only when using the zoom command. If it's the case, is it be possible to have a permanent display?
I don't know if the plugin is still supported.
If it's not the case, are there some alternate solutions?

The obvious way to fix a problem with a plugin is to make the change yourself and offer it back to the maintainer - if there is no longer a maintainer then you can take over that role and make the changes.
